# Split dataframe factor column's deliminated contents into multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe that is constituted by 5 factor columns. One of these columns `(D)` contains 200 values (on each row) separated by a comma delimiter `','`. What I am trying to accomplish is to split this column `(D)` into 200 columns in the same dataframe if possible.

```
data= data.frame(A = c('12223','168723','885441','99855'), 
                 B=c('855547','98557','699854','345871'), 
                 C=c('US', 'US', 'UK', 'IT'), 
                 D=c('0.54,0.589,0.55,0.69,0.88,0.98'
                     ,'0.36,0.38,0.66,0.84,0.22,0.33'
                     ,'0.67,0.89,0.94,0.85,0.78,0.98'
                     ,'0.14,0.12,0.13,0.11,0.17,0.19'), 
                 E=c('1','0','1','1'))
```

I've tried to use the separate function from `tidyr` but I get an error:

> Error in Math.factor(var) : ‘abs’ not meaningful for factors

```
data %>% separate(data$D, into = paste("V", 1:6, sep = "_"), sep=',')
```

Comment: Just remove the `$` from `separate`, i.e. `data %>% separate(D, into = paste("V", 1:6, sep = "_"), sep=',')`

Comment: In base R, do `cbind(dat[c(1,2,3,5)], do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(as.character(dat[[4]]), ","), as.numeric)))` and then rename variables.

Comment: I saw that post Aramis7d but because, as Sotos stated, I used `data$D` instead of `D` in the `seperate` that's why I couldn't find a solution. 
Sotos, if you please could you post it as an answer? Thanks